# Writing common scripts across flavours of linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, centos

I want to write few scripts (bash) which should work on all flavours of linux (mainly on ubuntu, centOs, redhat).

How can I make scripts independent of OS type?

Is there some online convertor to make scripts compatible with other versions of linux?

Or what is the best way to handle this scenario.

Comment: If you only need bash, the versions per distributions are the most annoying fact to take into account. ...1. Suggest to collect the version info on these platforms for bash and look up the changes. 2. More often than not, the shell scripts I know are the glue between calls to other programs, which have versions and (missing) options per version too ... and be sure, if there is no korn or z or c or whatnot shell on one platform, so you can concentrate on bash syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Use only POSIX shell standard features. On this link you can see more information about this subject and how to verify if a shell is POSIX compliant:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48786/how-can-i-test-for-posix-compliance-for-shell-scripts

Answer (score 0):

First. You have to make sure your script is compatible with some shell(s) version, in regard to the commands you run.

Second. You've to test the compatibility running your script and checking if it is doing what it suppose to do.

Third. If you've to run/read/write some files/directories in different distros, you've to write a pre-run script whose aim is to check the paths of the mentioned files/directories, and set them to variables which will be used by your script.

For example: Your script needs to run some binary, but you don't know where really is it. You check and find out this binary is located in different places depending on the distro:

1- In Ubuntu is in `/usr/bin/somebinary`

2- In CentOs is in `/bin/somebinary`

Therefore, your pre-run script would do:

```
SOMEBINARY_FULLPATH=$(whereis somebinary)
```

Or something like that. The same would be done if the same binary has different parameters, depending on the distro you run (it would be noted, for example, between grep versions in Linux and *BSD)

Finally, use the variables to run your commands.

Regards.